# How to build a function that detects crossover points on 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an assignment, I have to write a function that can detect cross over points in two lists. The function is to analyse financial data. So for example, I have two lists of prices (moving averages) as input, and as output I want two separate lists, 1 with the when  those prices (moving averages) intersect (i.e times index), and 1 determining which list is higher at point of intersection (I.e higher indeX). I am having trouble coming up with the correct syntax to define the criteria above on python. So far I haven't written anything, since I am stuck. Has anybody done anything similar, are there any tips.

Additional info, the assignment concerns moving averages and checking when moving averages intersect. I have been able to write a function that detects moving averages, but I am stuck on this part. Sorry for the lack of code and information. I am pretty sure copy pasting the entire assignment criteria is discouraged here so I tried to explain what my problem is.

```
    Identify cross-over indices for two equal-length lists of prices (here: moving averages)

Parameters:
    prices1, prices2: lists of prices (ordered by time)

Returns:
    list of crossover points

Each item in the returned list is a list [time_index, higher_index], where:
    - time_index is the crossover time index (when it happends
    - higher_index indicates which price becomes higher at timeIndex: either 1 for first list or 2 for second list

There are no crossovers before both price lists have values that are not None.
You can start making comparisons from the point at which both have number values.

Example use:
>>> p1 = [1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> p2 = [0, 2.5, 5, 3]
>>> cross_overs(p1, p2)
[[1, 2], [3, 1]]
>>> p1 = [None, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5]
>>> p2 = [None, None, 3.0, 4.0, 4.333333333333333, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.6666666666666665]
>>> cross_overs(p1, p2)
[[5, 2], [8, 1]]
"""
```

for the first part (i.e identyfying when intersection happened this is what i tried. but as you can see, the result i got is incorrect.

```
def cross_overs(prices1, prices2):
    times_index = list(set(prices1).intersection(set(prices2)))
    print (times_index)

(input)
p1 = [1, 2, 4, 5]
p2 = [0, 2.5, 5, 3]
cross_overs(p1, p2)    

(output)
[5]
```

Comment: can you give us a numerical example?

Comment: Please add a concrete example when introducing a problem. Input datastructures, desired output datastructures and the code you have already written trying to get that output along with an explanation of what the error is.

Comment: i have edited my post and added, my attempt and the examples and what problem i am facing. grateful for your time and consideration

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, with comments to explain the process, for your problem:

```
def cross_over(p1, p2):
    p1_none_index = 0
    p2_none_index = 0

    # Find indices of last occurences of None in both lists.
    try:
        p1_none_index = len(p1) - p1[::-1].index(None)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        p2_none_index = len(p2) - p2[::-1].index(None)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    # Take the maximum index of these indices.
    startingIndex = max(0, max(p1_none_index, p2_none_index))
    crossOvers = []

    #Take the difference of each pair.
    subtraction = [0] * startingIndex + [p1[i]-p2[i] for i in range(startingIndex,len(p1),1)]

    #Check using product, to track positive or negative sign changes in order to see if there is a crossover point.
    for i in range(1,len(subtraction),1):
        if subtraction[i] * subtraction[i-1] < 0:
            if subtraction[i] > 0:
                crossOvers.append([i,1])
            else:
                crossOvers.append([i,2])
    return crossOvers
```

Running it with the data you provided:

First:

```
p1 = [1, 2, 4, 5]
p2 = [0, 2.5, 5, 3]

crossOvers = cross_over(p1, p2)
print(crossOvers)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 1]]
```

Second:

```
p1 = [None, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5]
p2 = [None, None, 3.0, 4.0, 4.333333333333333, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.6666666666666665]

crossOvers = cross_over(p1, p2)
print(crossOvers)
```

Result:

```
[[5, 2], [8, 1]]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. i am a beginner and i have a lot to learn. having these comments really helps me understand where i lack knowledge and where to focus my practise for the future. you guys are amazing!!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def crossovers(p1,p2):
...     a = []
...     high = True
...     for i in range(len(p1)):
...         if p1[i] is not None and p2[i] is not None:
...             if high and p1[i] < p2[i]:
...                 a.append([i,2])
...                 high = False
...             if not high and p1[i] > p2[i]:
...                 a.append([i,1])
...                 high = True
...     return a
... 
>>>
```

This solution might work.

```
>>> p1 = [1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> p2 = [0, 2.5, 5, 3]
>>> 
>>> print(crossovers(p1,p2))
[[1, 2], [3, 1]]
>>> 
>>> p1 = [None, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5]
>>> p2 = [None, None, 3.0, 4.0, 4.333333333333333, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.6666666666666665]
>>> print(crossovers(p1,p2))
[[5, 2], [8, 1]]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. i am a beginner and i have a lot to learn. having these comments really helps me understand where i lack knowledge and where to focus my practise for the future. you guys are amazing!!